# Align the button to the right in Databtables

Tags: angular, angular-datatables

I have a button to export the table in to csv file , it should be aligned to the  top right of the data table, but I am not able to align it to right

If I inspect ,  I see a class dt-buttons , if I apply the css there in the page , I can see the change but not in the code. Need some assistance in this

This is what I have tried :

```
 dom: 'lBfrtip',
  buttons: [
    {
      text: 'Export to CSV',
      className: 'btn btn-outlined',
      align: 'button-right',
      action: function(e, dt, node, config) {
        console.log('Exporting to CSV...');
      }
    }
  ],
```

Note : I have tried applying CSS  but didn't help.